# Hide and show utilización

Tags: jquery

Compañeros, necesito ayuda para este código, tengo un formulario en una función y lo llamo cuando seleccionan una opción en en un select, pero necesito que se esconda un textarea, pero no me lo oculta ,me podrían ayudar...

```
.on('change','#estadoTicket',function(){
        console.log($(this));
        dat={'action':'mostrarFormTickets'};
        $.post(ajaxurl,dat,function(response){
            $('#observacionesTicket').hide(response);
            $('#FormularioTicket').show();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Tienes algun error?  Porque le pasas el `response` a la funcion `hide()`?

Comment: No, es el problema, cuando checo en la inspección de elementos la respuesta si me pone el formulario

Comment: Donde debería ir el response?

Comment: depente tu logica el response es la respuesta de la peticion POST que haces dicha respuesta debe ser con un proposito... pero el hide de jquery no la debe recibir

Comment: Esto ni siquiera es PHP, amigo, estás usando JavaScript y la librería `jQuery` para el mismo...

Comment: Lo siento, puse de rápido la etiqueta...